# Not able to deploy C# SQL CLR database project from Visual Studio 2010 to SQL Server 2014

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlclr, .net-framework-version

I have Visual Studio 2010 Professional and SQL Server 2014. I have created a very simple SQL CLR database application which will just printing a message after an insertion happen in a table. There is no error when I build the application but whenever I try to deploy it I am getting the error:

> SqlClrDeploy:
>   Beginning deployment of assembly TestCLR.dll to server WIN-GECJT\SQLEXPRESS : Checkbox
>   The following error might appear if you deploy a SQL CLR project that was built for a version of the .NET Framework that is incompatible with the target instance of SQL Server: "Deploy error SQL01268: CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly failed because assembly failed verification". To resolve this issue, open the properties for the project, and change the .NET Framework version.
>
> C:\ProgramFiles\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudiov10.0\TeamDataMicrosoft.Data.Schema.SqlClr.targets(96,5): Deploy error SQL01234: The database version is not supported.
>
> Build FAILED.

I have also tested it by changing my project's target framework to 2.0 and 3.5 but getting the same error every time.

When I run the below command to see My SQL Server 2014 CLR version:

```
select * from sys.dm_clr_properties;
```

It shows me version **v4.0.30319**

If Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2014 has the same version v4.0 then why I am getting this compatibility error?

Or we just cannot simply deploy SQL CLR 2010 project on SQL Server 2014?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this is common issue for incompatibility between SQLCLR shipped with VS2010 and SQL Server newer versions (2012 to 2014).

> In your case here the problem is raised from the template used to
>   create the SQL Server solution , so VS2010 Template wont deploy to
>   SQL Server 2012 or newer.

by upgrading the actual template to the latest one your issue disappear.

> STEPS :  On VS2010 Chose new Project. From templates Select as shown
>   below (Other Languages -> SQL Server ->Sql Server Data Tools Database
>   Projects (Web Insall)):

At this point you have to follow the steps to install SSDT 2012 or 2014 not 2010 (installation may take long time just let it go!!)

SSDT being installed Choose File --> New Project --> SQL Server Database Project

to create a new one 
![New Project Dialog with SSDT 2012/2014 installed this time][2]

Or just Convert your existing Projects to the new installed Template as bellow 
![Contextual Menu To Convert Existing Project to the new Template.][3]

Hope this Will Help.